# How to call struct using string value in swift 4

Tags: swift

**JSON**

```
{
  "method" : 105,
  "values" : {
    "item_image" : "A123",
    "name" : "Image1",
    "description" : "Sample Description"
  },
  "columns" : {
    "name" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "source" : "name"
    },
    "item_image" : {
      "type" : "image",
      "source" : "item_image"
    },
    "description" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "source" : "description"
    }
  }
}
```

**Model**

```
struct Params:Decodable {
  let values: Values
  let columns: [String: Columns]
}

struct Columns: Decodable {
  let source: String
  let type: String
}

struct Values: Decodable {
  let name: String
  let item_image: String
  let description: String
}
```

**Code**

```
for (_, val) in param.columns {
    colType = val.type
    colSource += ", \(val.source)"
    let s = "param.values.\(val.source)" \\this line is invalid
    let vals = s
    print("value: ",vals)
}
```

Hi! Im working with the lines of code above, and I'm having a problem to call my struct. Instead of using static values i want it dynamic with the code below but its invalid:

```
let s = "param.values.\(val.source)"
```

invalid because when it comes to this line:

```
let vals = s
```

the result is param.values.name or param.values.item_image, my expected value is Image1 or A123.

to make it clear here's the expected value from the codes and how can I achieve this:

```
for (_, val) in param.columns {
    colType = val.type! expectedvalue= text
    colSource += ", \(val.source)" expectedvalue= ", name, item_image, description"
    let s = "param.values.\(val.source)" expectedvalue: "param.values.name" or "param.values.item_image"
    let vals = s expectedvalue: Image1 or A123
    print("value: ",vals) expectedvalue: value: Image1
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: so you generate a string pattern like `param.values.name` & then want to translate it to map the actual objects `param`->`values`->`name` to return eventually `Image1`?

Comment: yes sir, how can i achieve that?

Comment: no, i don't know if a type can be generated from a string. It reminds me of `NSClassFromString` that creates a class instance by providing the class name in `String` format. Sorry mate.

Comment: I see, it's okay sir. i've been searching this for the whole day, maybe there is no answer for this. I guess i have to use a static pattern and another loop to got the values that i wanted. :D

Comment: if you plan to use a static pattern then I could share an answer that might work. it's a simple logic so... should i post an answer then?

Comment: i already had, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access a property by string. One solution could be to create a mapper function that actually handles that. Still, this assumes that you have pre-determined keys.

```
struct Params:Decodable {
    let values: Values
    let columns: [String: Columns]

    func getValues(from columns: Columns) -> String? {
        switch columns.source {
        case "item_image":
            return values.item_image
        case "name":
            return values.name
        case "description":
            return values.description
        default:()
        }
        if columns.source == "item_image" {
            return values.item_image
        }
        return nil
    }
}

struct Columns: Decodable {
    let source: String
    let type: String
}

struct Values: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let item_image: String
    let description: String
}

let column = Columns(source: "name", type: "text")
let column2 = Columns(source: "item_image", type: "image")
let column3 = Columns(source: "description", type: "text")

let values = Values(name: "Image1", item_image: "A123", description: "Sample Description")

let params = Params(values: values, columns: ["name": column, "item_image": column2, "description": column3])

let name = params.getValues(from: column) //Image1
let itemImage = params.getValues(from: column2) //A123
let description = params.getValues(from: column3) //Sample Description
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, but i already seen this structure on another question. not what im looking for. :D